# What is this double "be" meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given the sentence:

> He didn’t have a clue what was going on, but he didn’t seem **to be being expelled**, and some of the feeling started coming back to his legs.

I guess that in ‘*to be being expelled*,’ ‘be’ is for making passive voice and ‘being’ is for the meaning of future, that is, ‘to be expelled’ would be being happened in near future. Is this the right guessing?

Comment: It's an awkward sentence for sure. But maybe some more context would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*to be being expelled* is a **present continuous passive**, with the head verb cast into the **infinitive** so the phrase may serve as the ‘object’ of the verb *seem*:

> (he) **was** being expelled ⇨ **to be** being expelled

So the middle clause of your sentence may be understood as

> and it did not appear that he was being expelled

Answer (score 3):

You correctly identified `be` as passive, but `being` makes this a continuous, not future: *in the process of being expelled*.

It's a variation on *I'm being [state]*, a common passive continuous form, differentiating this from one finalized: "I am being drenched" means "I'm under a downpour of water, which keeps drenching me." This is different from "I am drenched" which you'd say as you exit from rain into a shelter, when you're wet but no longer getting more wet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything odd in the sentence. An accidental juxtaposition of words need not confuse the reader so long as the sentence can be correctly parsed.

> {He didn’t have a clue what was going on, but}
>
> {**he didn’t seem to be**} ...  — {it did not appear like he was}
>
> ... {**being expelled**},  — {going to be thrown out}
>
> {and some of the feeling started coming back to his legs.}

That should clarify, I believe.